# Extract Enums with brackets in comments?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

The Enum I want to extract is like following:

```cs
...
other code 
...
enum A
{
  a,
  b=2,
  c=3,
  d//{x}
}
...
More Enums like the above.
...
```

First, I have tried using the Option `Singleline` with Regex:
`enum\s*\w+\s*{.*?\}`

However, since the comments have brackets.The regex doesn't work. It will stop when it runs to the bracket in comments.

So I tried excluding the bracket after comments. Based on what I have searched so far,it seems I need Negative look ahead with grouping construct `Multiline`.

Then I tried parsing the brackets without comments ahead.
The substep is to find brackets after comments:
`(?m:^.*?//.*?}.*?$)`.

However, it seems the `.` still match anychar including newline even in inline multiline mode.

Then I tried using multiline in the first place. Since the main problem is the brackets in comments.I tried:
`(?!//.*)}`
Negative look ahead doesn't work the way I expected.

Here is a [csharp-regex-test-link](http://regexstorm.net/tester) for you to test.

To summarize, I need parse enum from a csharp source code file.

The main problem to me is the brackets in comments.

**Edit**:
To clarify

1.brackets in comments are in pairs. For example:

```
xxx=xxx; //{xx}
```

2.comments are only in the form of `//`

3.I can't rely on indentations.

Comment: Not sure if `.NET` supports recursion, but if so, you could use https://regex101.com/r/AAuHg2/1/ If not, you could use balanced group constructs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition

Comment: If your code is well-indented (with starting and ending `{` on their own lines), you may leverage that: `(?ms)enum\s*\w+\s*^{.*?^}\r?$`. You can't rely on balanced groups because `{` and `}` in the comments do not have to be balanced. Recursion would not have helped had it been there in .NET regex.

Comment: @Jan That won't work because comments may contain `// text } here`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Why should recursion not help here? See https://regex101.com/r/AAuHg2/1/

Comment: @Jan https://regex101.com/r/AAuHg2/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't rely on indentation. But the brackets in comments are in pairs. Thanks. I will try to translate yours into .NET regex to see if it helps.

Comment: You may try `@"\benum\s*\w+\s*{(?>[^{}]+|(?<o>){|(?<-o>)})*(?(o)(?!)|)}"`. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbenum%5cs*%5cw%2b%5cs*%7b%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%29%7b%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%29%7d%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%7d&i=enum+A%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++a%2c%0d%0a++b%3d2%2c%0d%0a++c%3d3%2c%0d%0a++d%2f%2f%7bx%7d%0d%0a%7d%0d%0a...%0d%0aMore+Enums+like+the+above.%0d%0a...).

Comment: Isn't the attempt to parse source code with Regex the same wrong approach as [parsing HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/107625)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works. Thanks.

Comment: @UweKeim Probably right. However it depends. I have used roslyn to parse c# code. However, there are some constraints in production. Using the right way may not be the right solution.But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
@"\benum\s*\w+\s*{(?>[^{}]+|(?<o>){|(?<-o>)})*(?(o)(?!)|)}"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cbenum%5Cs%2A%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2A%7B%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%7B%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%7D%29%2A%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%7D&i=enum%20A%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3D2%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3D3%2C%0D%0A%20%20d%2F%2F%7Bx%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A...%0D%0AMore%20Enums%20like%20the%20above.%0D%0A...)

**Details**

- `\benum` - a whole word `enum`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `{` - a `{` char
- `(?>[^{}]+|(?<o>){|(?<-o>)})*` - either 1+ chars other than `{` and `}`, or a `{` with an empty string pushed onto the Group `o` stack, or `}` with a value popped from Group `o` stack
- `(?(o)(?!)|)` - a conditional `yes-no` construct that fails the match and makes the regex engine backtrack at the current location if Group `o` still has any items left on the stack
- `}` - a `}` char.

Comment: About the conditional yes-no, why you add `|`? What is the difference between `(?(o)(?!))` and `(?(o)(?!)|)`?

Comment: @AlexWei It is usually used without `|` in the balanced construct, but to keep it consistent with the regex grammar, the empty no part pattern is welcome. In other situations, missing no part might lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do your task with a single regex. What if you have a string that looks like

```
var notEnum = "enum A {a, b, c}";
```

Hovewer you can capture your enums with few passes. Take a look at this algorithm

1. Clear strings content
2. Drop singleline comments
3. Drop muliline comments
4. Use you original regex

Example:

```
var code = ...

var stringLiterals = new Regex("\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var multilineComments = new Regex("/\\*.*?\\*/", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
var singlelineComments = new Regex("//.*$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var @enum = new Regex("enum\\s*\\w+\\s*{.*?}", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);

code = stringLiterals.Replace(code, m => "\"\"");
code = multilineComments.Replace(code, m => "");
code = singlelineComments.Replace(code, m => "");

var enums = @enum.Matches(code).Cast<Match>().ToArray();

foreach (var match in enums)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```